# How much space do I need for SVN?

Tags: iphone, svn

I am currently setting up a SVN server for use with a single iPad application.

How much space would be a good recommendation assuming I am only going to have a few iPad App under 10.

Comment: It purely depends on the app :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good guide to is to look at what commercial SVN providers give in their packages. Find a package that describes your situation, and look at how much space they provide, then use allocate that much space on your own system.

Examples:
http://unfuddle.com/about/tour/plans

https://www.assembla.com/plans

http://www.svnhostingcomparison.com/

Answer (score 2):

The size of the application as it is right now isn't going to dictate how much space you need so much as how long you will be developing it for. With a huge number of revisions, any project will become large in the SVN repository.

I would recommend giving yourself plenty of room for expansion, and then adding disk space later if you require. You don't need to plan for the final size of the repository right now.